# tradingview widget real-time chart change price

Tags: javascript, tradingview-api

I am using tradingview widget with javascript. When the page loads, BTCUSDT is the USDT equivalent. In the upper right corner, we can change the currency of a different country from the price conversion. Is it possible to select different country automatically with widget settings on code??

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        new TradingView.widget({
                            "width": "100%",
                            "height": "100%",
                            "symbol": "<?php echo $pairname; ?>USDT",
                            "interval": "D",
                            "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
                            "theme": "dark",
                            "style": "1",
                            "locale": "tr",
                            "currencies": "KWD",
                            "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
                            "enable_publishing": false,
                            "allow_symbol_change": true,
                            "container_id": "tradingview_b75ce"
                        });
                    </script>
```